# Jquery Tools Overlay call on javascript function

Tags: jquery, overlay, jquery-tools

I have a jquery overlay window in my html alongwith a button to activate here is the code.

```
<!-- Validation Overlay Box -->
<div class="modal" id="yesno" style="top: 100px; left: 320px; position: relative; display: none; z-index: 0; margin-top: 100px;">
    <h2>  &nbsp;&nbsp;Authentication Failed</h2>

    <p style="font-family:Arial; font-size:small; text-align:center">
       Ether your username or password has been entered incorrectly.
       Please make sure that your username or password entered correctly...
    </p>

    <!-- yes/no buttons -->
    <p align="center">
        <button class="close"> OK </button>
    </p>
</div>
```

### Here is the Jquery tools Script

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({
        // some mask tweaks suitable for modal dialogs
        mask: {
            color: '#a2a2a2',
            loadSpeed: 200,
            opacity: 0.9
        },
        closeOnClick: false
    });

    var buttons = $("#yesno button").click(function(e) {
        // get user input
        var yes = buttons.index(this) === 0;

        // do something with the answer
        triggers.eq(0).html("You clicked " + (yes ? "yes" : "no"));
    });

    $("#prompt form").submit(function(e) {
        // close the overlay
        triggers.eq(1).overlay().close();

        // get user input
        var input = $("input", this).val();

        // do something with the answer
        triggers.eq(1).html(input);

        // do not submit the form
        return e.preventDefault();
    });

});
</SCRIPT>
```

### And here how its called upon clicking on a button or a hyperlink

```
"<BUTTON class="modalInput" rel="#yesno">You clicked no</BUTTON>"
```

All i want is I dont want to show the overlay on clicking on button or through a link. Is it possible to call it through a javascript function like "showOverlay()" ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 options, there's a [`load` option](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay/index.html) you can use, like this:

```
var triggers = $(".modalInput").overlay({
 mask: {
  color: '#a2a2a2',
  loadSpeed: 200,
  opacity: 0.9
 },
 closeOnClick: false,
 load: true
});
```

This makes it open immediately, [you can see the API demo here](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/overlay/trigger.html).  If what you're after is to just show the overlay at some point later *after* setting it up, just trigger the event it's bound to, `click`, like this:

```
$(".modalInput").click();
```

This triggers the same handler behavior as actually clicking a button or link would, opening the overlay.